# Upon reading a chkdsk log, how to determine if bad sectors were analyzed?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, check-disk

I have performed a chkdsk on one of my external hdd's
I'm  not sure however if bad sectors were checked as well (chkdsk /r)

How can I be sure they were checked if I don't remember the command line I used?

Example:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Chkdsk
Date:          13/11/2017 20:03:40
Event ID:      26214
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Admin2-PC
Description:
Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode.  

Checking file system on G:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is TOSHIBA EXT.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 5)...
  46848 file records processed.                                
         File verification completed.
  0 large file records processed.                                    
 0 bad file records processed.                                   
    0 EA records processed.                                        
     0 reparse records processed.                                     
 CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 5)...
  51472 index entries processed.                                     
   Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.                                      
    0 unindexed files recovered.                                    
  CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 5)...
  46848 file SDs/SIDs processed.                                      
  Cleaning up 3 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 3 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 3 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  2312 data files processed.                                  
         CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
  46832 files processed.                                       
         File data verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)...
  150353095 free clusters processed.                                   
     Free space verification is complete.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

   4769177 MB total disk space.
   4181587 MB in 44366 files.
     18220 KB in 2314 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    261839 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 601412384 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
1220909567 total allocation units on disk.
 150353096 allocation units available on disk.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Chkdsk" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">26214</EventID>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-11-13T20:03:40.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>53581</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Admin2-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>

Checking file system on G:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is TOSHIBA EXT.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 5)...
  46848 file records processed.                                     
    File verification completed.
  0 large file records processed.                                  
   0 bad file records processed.                             
          0 EA records processed.                                 
            0 reparse records processed.                                
      CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 5)...
  51472 index entries processed.                              
          Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.                                     
     0 unindexed files recovered.                                  
    CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 5)...
  46848 file SDs/SIDs processed.                                  
      Cleaning up 3 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 3 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 3 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  2312 data files processed.                                       
    CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
  46832 files processed.                                            
    File data verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)...
  150353095 free clusters processed.                                   
     Free space verification is complete.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

   4769177 MB total disk space.
   4181587 MB in 44366 files.
     18220 KB in 2314 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    261839 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 601412384 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
1220909567 total allocation units on disk.
 150353096 allocation units available on disk.
</Data>
    <Binary>00B7000063B60000EC2001000000000078000000000000000000000000000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Look in the [System Event Log](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/96938-check-disk-chkdsk-read-event-viewer-log.html)

Comment: I did, I have the log, but the log doesn't tell me if it was chkdsk /r or /f that i used.

Comment: No, but it tells you **what** was checked.

Comment: Not explicitly. That's the reason why I placed the question.

Comment: Please include the event log output in your question.

Comment: Looks like you didn't check for bad sectors

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: @DavidPostill It would have said so.

Comment: it says 0kb in bad sectrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stage 4 and Stage 5 are the cluster evaluation stages of `chkdsk /r`. There are only 3 stages used with `chkdsk /f`.

Your scan log indicates stage 4 and stage 5 completed without problems. Therefore, `chkdsk /r` was used and no bad clusters were found.

[5 Phases of Check Disk Utility - The Internal Working](http://windowsanatomy.blogspot.com/2015/12/5-phases-of-check-disk-utility-internal.html?m=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
4769177 MB total disk space.
   4181587 MB in 44366 files.
     18220 KB in 2314 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    261839 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 601412384 KB available on disk.
```

As it shows here with the "0 KB in bad sectors", it found no bad sectors on the hard drive.